# A curious way to write the eigenvectors of the Boolean hypercube

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-graph-theory

It seems that one can write the eigenvectors of the hypercube $\{ \pm 1\}^n$ as the functions, $\{ \chi_S \}_{S \subseteq [n] }$. And these functions $\chi_S$ are defined on the vertices $x \in \{ \pm 1\}^n$ as $\chi_S (x) = \prod_{i \in S} x_i$. And the eigenvalue of $\chi_S$ is $\vert S \vert/n$

- Even on $n=2$ I am not able to check this to be true. What is the justification for this above formulation?

Comment: I'm a little confused. In what sense does a cube have eigenvectors? Is there a transformation happening somewhere?

Comment: As eigenvectors of the graph that is the Boolean hypercube.

Comment: The eigenvalue should be $n-2|S|$, no?

Comment: Shouldn't it depend on whether or not these are some normalized Laplacians or not? (like may be take L = I - A/d) ?

Comment: You need to specify what matrix your eigenvalues/vectors are for. My comment assumed you were talkng about the adjacency matrix, but perhaps not?

Comment: I think this is true for $L = I - \frac{A}{n}$. Though I can't see a simple way to see that.

Answer (score 2):

Your eigenvalue of $L$ is slightly wrong if $L:=I-\frac{1}{n}A$ where $A$ is the adjacency matrix of the hypercube graph $Q_n$. The correct eigenvalue for the given eigenvector is $2\frac{|S|}{n}$ as I show below.

First we show $\chi_S$ is an eigenvector for $A$ (with an eigenvalue $\lambda_S$ that will be pop out from the proof of this). To do this, you need to check that for every vertex $v$, the sum of all $\chi_S(x)$ over all vertices $x$ that are adjacent to $v$ is equal to $\lambda_S\chi_S(v)$.

Well, the vertices adjacent to $v$ are those in which $v$ and $x$ differ in one position, say $i$. When $i\not\in S$, we have $\chi_S(v)=\chi_S(x)$. If $i\in S$, then $\chi_S(x)=-\chi_S(v)$. Hence, $$\sum_{x\sim v}\chi_S(x) = (n-|S|)\chi_S(v)+|S|(-\chi_S(v))=(n-2|S|)\chi_S(v).$$

So $\chi_S$ is an eigenvector for $A$ with eigenvalue $n-2|S|$. It follows that $$1-\frac{1}{n}(n-2|S|) = \frac{2|S|}{n}$$ is an eigenvalue of $L$ with eigenvector $\chi_S$.